# Reactive Framework Hello World

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This is [an easy program to introduce the Reactive Framework](http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2009/11/reactive-framework-hello-world.html). But I want to try the error handler, by modifying the program to be:

```
var cookiePieces = Observable.Range(1, 10);
cookiePieces.Subscribe(x =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}! {0} pieces of cookie!", x);
      throw new Exception();  // newly added by myself
   },
      ex => Console.WriteLine("the exception message..."),
      () => Console.WriteLine("Ah! Ah! Ah! Ah!"));
Console.ReadLine();
```

In this sample the follwing overload is used.

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<TSource>(
     this IObservable<TSource> source, 
     Action<TSource> onNext, 
     Action<Exception> onError, 
     Action onCompleted);
```

I hoped I would see the exception message printed, but the console application crashed. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception handler is used for exceptions created in the observable itself, not by the observer.

An easy way to provoke the exception handler is something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xs = Observable.Range(1, 10)
                           .Select(x => 10 / (5 - x));

        xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", x),
                     ex => Console.WriteLine("Bang! {0}", ex),
                     () => Console.WriteLine("Done"));

        Console.WriteLine("App ending normally");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Received 2
Received 3
Received 5
Received 10
Bang! System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at Test.<Main>b__0(Int32 x)
   at System.Linq.Observable.<>c__DisplayClass35a`2.<>c__DisplayClass35c.<Select
>b__359(TSource x)
App ending normally
```

Comment: I think you are right, however the example you gave will not print the ex message, either. The app will crush with Divided By Zero Exception.

Comment: @Danny: Not on my box... I ran this example and it printed out "Bang!" and the exception. If you ran the full example and the exception was propagated, could you indicate which version of Rx and .NET you're using?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Rx for .NET 4, .NET 4 on VS2010

Comment: @Danny: I've edited the example to show an extra line at the end, which is displayed perfectly normally. Could you give details about what you mean by "the app will crush"? Is it just breaking into the debugger?

Comment: @Danny: Try it without using the debugger at all. It will be fine. I suspect it's breaking into the debugger due to debugger settings... but if you just hit F5 when it breaks in, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the Rx library, any user code passed into an operator that works on IObservable (Select, Where, GroupBy etc...) will be caught and send to the OnError handler of observers subscribed to the observable. The reason these are handled is that they are part of the computation.

Exceptions occurring in Observer code will have to be handled by the user. As they're at the end of the computation, it is unclear to Rx how to handle these.

Comment: Listen to the man, I have a hunch he knows what he is talking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does it really crash or jumps Visual Studio into and shows you that an exception happened? If the second is true, you should take a look into Debug - Exception within the menu bar and deselect everything on the right.